# Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1:run (default-cli) after removing dependency

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a JavaFX Maven project that suddenly threw an error after removing a dependency. The dependency was added only a couple minutes prior and is not and was not used or referenced by any code in the project. No other files than the `pom` file have been touched since adding the dependency. I did update/reimport the `pom` file.

The code worked as expected before and while dependency was added, only stopped when removing the dependency.

**The error is as follows:**

```
Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1:run (default-cli) on project computer: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
```

**Here is my pom file with the dependency I removed:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>computer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- This is the dependency I removed
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.computer.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Edit:**
For additional information:
when reimporting the dependency, it is still not working.

**Edit 2:**
I tried running from the command prompt instead. Now I get this error:

```
No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

I have the java 13.0.2 jdk installed, and it worked properly before.

**Edit 3:**

I have now tried to reinstall Intellij, the java 13.0.2 JDK, Maven, and set up fresh environment variables. Nothing works. Even brand new JavaFX Maven projects won't work now.

**This is the run configuration in IntelliJ:**

```
clean:clean javafx:compile javafx:run -f pom.xml -f pom.xml -f pom.xml
```

**Build Log when running in intelliJ:**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\mats\Documents\intellij-projects\computer "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=50370:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2020.1.1 clean:clean javafx:compile javafx:run -f pom.xml -f pom.xml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< org.example:computer >------------------------
[INFO] Building computer 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-cli) @ computer ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\mats\Documents\intellij-projects\computer\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1:compile (default-cli) @ computer ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 14 source files to C:\Users\mats\Documents\intellij-projects\computer\target\classes
[INFO] /C:/Users/mats/Documents/intellij-projects/computer/src/main/java/org/computer/io/WriteToCSV.java: C:\Users\mats\Documents\intellij-projects\computer\src\main\java\org\computer\io\WriteToCSV.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /C:/Users/mats/Documents/intellij-projects/computer/src/main/java/org/computer/io/WriteToCSV.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1:run (default-cli) @ computer ---
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: --module-path
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXRunMojo.java:525)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXRunMojo.java:487)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute (JavaFXRunMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXRunMojo.java:525)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXRunMojo.java:487)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.314 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-12T18:47:29+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1:run (default-cli) on project computer: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Hello Mats. Did you try to hit ‘mvn clean install’ before/after reimporting the dependency?

Comment: @HuserB1989 yes is did

Comment: Regarding your command line attempt, check what's the JDK that maven is referring to by `mvn -version`. Because that might be different from what's running in the IDE. Also, shall we pass `-e` to check if we can get a detailed stack trace of the failure.

Comment: @NipunThathsara When I ran `mvn -version` I got `jre1.8`. That is obviously wrong, but how do I change it?

Comment: @Mats, try changing the `JAVA_HOME` and test in a new terminal. (Or source the respective profile for the changes to make effect)

Comment: @NipunThathsara Thank you! That worked. I managed to get the `mvn -version` to `13.0.2`. Now the compile works and I can run the application from the command line. However, I still have the same error when trying to run from IntelliJ.

Comment: @Mats, Can you please attach the build log to see the detailed failure?

Comment: @NipunThathsara I added the build log as well as the run configuration I have set up to the bottom of the main  post

Comment: issue seems to be `Unrecognized option: --module-path` and you can try the answer provided here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55855335/javafx-and-maven-in-intellij-java-home-set-but-unrecognized-option-module-pa   Give it a try.

Comment: @NipunThathsara
If I understand correctly, I am already doing the things described as the solution you gave. But it put me on the right track, and I found the solution. 
The solution was to add this line to my `javafx-maven-plugin` inside the `<configuration> ` tags:
`<executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java</executable>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After much back and forth, I found the solution [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven):

Under the last step of `JavaFx with IntelliJ > Non modular with Maven` it states:

- **Note:** In case JAVA_HOME is not set to 14, running from the Maven
  Projects window might fail. To avoid it, you can add the correct java
  command to the javafx-maven-plugin:
  `<configuration><executable>/path/to/jdk-12/bin/java</executable></configuration>`.

As my JAVA_HOME is set to 13.0.2, this solution applies to me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to configure it like this:

```
                <configuration>
                    <jlinkExecutable>/home/myuser/java/jdk-11/bin/jlink</jlinkExecutable>
                </configuration>
```

my complete pom file looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testes-diversos-javafx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testes-diversos-javafx</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>12.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tilesfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.48</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jlinkExecutable>/home/myuser/java/jdk-11/bin/jlink</jlinkExecutable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>
                                com.example.testesdiversosjavafx/com.example.testesdiversosjavafx.HelloApplication
                            </mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME in your environment before playing around with the configuration.  Also the $PATH value.  I had both of mine set to the wrong paths and ran into all kinds of issues including this one.  I would think the IDE (IntelliJ) would isolate the project by using a configuration specifically for the project but it did not.  As soon as I set those to valid values and restarted IntelliJ most of the issues on my project/system went away.