# How do I fix intellij 2022 gluonfx error: javafx:run@default-cli failed

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gluonfx

I followed instructions at https://gluonhq.com/developers/media/  video titled "Getting Started with Gluon in Intellij IDEA".  The steps  given in the video were to (1) install Intellij (I downloaded and installed intellij 2022.2.3 Community Edition on a Widows 10 OS), (2) install the Gluon plugin, (3) create a new project (the video showed selection of gluon multi view, but I selected a single view project), (4) select a JDK (the video showed selection of JDK 17, I selected JDK 19), (5) run the application from the Maven view window by clicking plugins/gluonfx:run and the video's application ran ok, but mine failed with the message, error: javafx:run@default-cli failed. A google search for this error on intellij gluon gave no results.

The error is thrown after a series of INFO lines in the run window, the last line reads to the effect that the plugin is running in a default cli. Then the error is given and the preceding lines are erased. I am quite new to IntelliJ and Gluon and will need assistance in debugging and log file viewing so I am sorry I can't offer more detail here.

Can this be fixed or why not?

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/a/61758740/18430882. Check mentions of JAVA_HOME in https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven

Comment: Yes, JAVA_HOME needed to be set to what IntelliJ Project Structure indicated I was using.